# fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, facebook

I am getting the log while login with Facebook. Kindly tell me how can i remove this log. I am working on ios8

Answer (score 141, accepted):

In your `info.plist`, add a row with the key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. Make sure it is of `array` type. For it's only element, add the string `fbauth2`.

[image]

Voila

Comment: how do i add the fbauth2 when LSApplicationQueriesSchemes make array type

Comment: arrays have elements. hover to the left of the entry to reveal the drop down.

Comment: Ok,  But it did not reveal.

Comment: Thanks kelvin, it reveals when i press "+" button

Comment: "Make sure it is of array type", I missed this point and had to spend crazy several hours in dealing with uncaught expections. Great that I landed here. Thank you @Kelvin

Comment: Just to be clear, the string `fbauth2` should not have quotes around it

Comment: do we add this at the main project info.plist?

Comment: @HongZhou yes, add it to your main target's info.plist

Answer (score 24):

just follow [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) link.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fbapi20130214</string>
    <string>fbapi20130410</string>
    <string>fbapi20130702</string>
    <string>fbapi20131010</string>
    <string>fbapi20131219</string>    
    <string>fbapi20140410</string>
    <string>fbapi20140116</string>
    <string>fbapi20150313</string>
    <string>fbapi20150629</string>
    <string>fbauth</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
</array>
```

Comment: for facebook sdk4.6 :   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>

Answer (score 11):

If you're using v4.6.0 or higher of the SDK, you only need to add into your Info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Comment: For iOS 9.0, it needs to be:

<string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>

Answer (score 8):

There is a new key, LSApplicationQueriesSchemes, and here you will need to add the list of schemes you want to are canOpenURL on.

[image]

Comment: how to manage this if you use it within a static framework that is embedded in a app?