# InvalidOperationException fbauth2 missing

Tags: facebook, xamarin.ios, fbsdk

I'm facing this issue consistently... before making it as duplicate question I gone through many sites but I didn't find any answer.

Here is the exception on that I got

"fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0"

Here is my Info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

I added all key for ios 9 but its showing above exception while sharing some content at facebook with **ShareDialog** its really frustrating :|

Can someone please help to resolve this

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fbauth2 is missing from your Info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes and is required for iOS 9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986475/fbauth2-is-missing-from-your-info-plist-under-lsapplicationqueriesschemes-and-is)